# Please help the date formating in dataweave2.0

Tags: dataweave, mule4

Please help me transforming the date-format from

> "Mon, 26 Sep 2022 14:51:04 +0000"

to this format

> "2022-09-26"

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change a date string format in DataWeave 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73816944/change-a-date-string-format-in-dataweave-2)

Comment: This kind of question has been previously asked and should be closed as a duplicate. Please refer to the link provided or search other answers.

Comment: looking to change the "Mon, 26 Sep 2022 14:51:04 +0000" to "2022-09-26" format. However I did not found help in the provided link.

%dw 2.0
output application/json
var value = "Mon, 26 Sep 2022 14:51:04 +0000"
---
date: value as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"}

tried with above one which is not solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must read your input in the incoming format, then you can transform your input to the desired format, here is an example of how you can achieve that,

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var inputDateTime = "Mon, 26 Sep 2022 14:51:04 +0000"
var myDateTime = inputDateTime as DateTime {format: "E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"}
---
myDateTime as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"}
```

I recommend you go over the documentation pages, for a better understanding of dates formatting in DataWeave 2,

1. https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-cookbook-format-dates
2. https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-format-dates-in-DataWeave-2
3. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-

Comment: Just take a look at [What is voting up?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)